# Principal Component Analysis, Eigenvectors lying in the span of the observed data points?

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

I have been reading several papers and articles related to Principal Component Analysis (PCA) and in some of them, there is one step which is quite unclear to me (in particular (3) in [[Schölkopf 1996](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/Kernel/kernelPCA_scholkopf.pdf)]).

Let me reproduce their reasoning below.

---

Consider the centered data set $D = \{\textbf{x}_k\}_{k=1}^M$ with $\textbf{x}_k \in \textbf{R}^N$ and $ \sum_{k=1}^M \textbf{x}_k = 0$. PCA diagonalizes the (sample) covariance matrix

$$
C = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M \textbf{x}_j \textbf{x}_j^T. \tag{1}
$$

To do this we find the solution to the eigenvector equation

$$
\lambda \textbf{v} = C \textbf{v} \tag{2}
$$

for eigenvalues $\lambda \geq 0$ and eigenvectors $\textbf{v} \in \textbf{R}^N\backslash \{{0}\}$. As

$$
\lambda \textbf{v} = C \textbf{v} = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M (\textbf{x}_j^T \textbf{v}) \textbf{x}_j, \tag{3}
$$

all solutions $\textbf{v}$ with $\lambda \neq 0$ must lie in the span of $\textbf{x}_1, \dots, \textbf{x}_M$, hence (2) is equivalent to

$$
\lambda(\textbf{x}_k^T \textbf{v}) = \textbf{x}_k^T C \textbf{v}, \qquad \text{for } k = 1, \dots, M \tag{4}
$$

---

In (4), doesn't $\lambda(\textbf{x}^T \textbf{v}) = \textbf{x}^T C \textbf{v}$ hold for $\textbf{any}$ value of $\textbf{x}$? Why does (4) only hold when $\textbf{x} \in D$? I do not understand how their end up with (4).

Thanks.

Comment: I got an answer in the data science stackexchange forum: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15886/principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-lying-in-the-span-of-the-observed-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right (4) holds for all $x\in D$ but what they are saying is that (2) and (4) are equivalent. (2) implies (4) is trivial but the point is (4) implies (2) as well. So solving (4) will give us $\bf v$ which satisfies (2). Now lets see why thats true, $$C\textbf{v}=\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M \textbf{x}_j \textbf{x}_j^T \textbf{v} = \frac{1}{\lambda M}\sum_{i=1}^M \textbf{x}_j \textbf{x}_j^T C\textbf{v}=\frac{1}{\lambda}C^2\textbf{v} $$ 
using (4) in the last equality. So we have,
$$C^2\textbf{v}-\lambda C\textbf{v}=0$$
$$C(C\textbf{v}-\lambda\textbf{v})=0$$
Now because no vector in the span of $\textbf{x}_i$'s can be in the null space of C, we have $C\textbf{v}-\lambda\textbf{v}=0$

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the explanation behind the reasoning of the paper. However, I do not understand how did you develop the first equality. @user1131274

Comment: I am using (4) there, $x_j^T v= \frac{1}{\lambda}x_j^TCv$.

Comment: What is exactly was meant with your last sentence "Now because no vector in the span of ..." ?

Answer (score 1):

I will hazard a guess, I assume the authors imply the following is true : if $v$ is a non-zero vector in the span of $C$ such that $\lambda x_k^T C = x_k^T C v$ for all $k$ then $\lambda v= C v.$

Comment: Thanks ! Do you know what is the proof of this? Or where could I find such a proof? @arin